# Optimizing group by query with union

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, gaps-and-islands

I have a MySQL table looking like this:

[image]

I want to find a query that groups my table like this:

[image]

Details:

`a_id` = delimited area on a map

`is_flag` = 1-if sensor is in area/ 0 - if sensor not in area

Basically the first table describes in which area my sensor was at each timestamp.

The second table tells me the period that my sensor stayed in and out of each area.

I am using the below query for each areas_id with union all in order to output in a single table, time periods of how my sensor traveled between areas and how much it stayed in/out each area.

```sql
select t.a_id, min(t.timestamp) starttime,max(t.timestamp) endtime, 
t.is_flag from(SELECT *,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.timestamp) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY 
a.is_flag ORDER BY a.timestamp) as GRP
FROM tablename a where areas_id=25 ) t
group by is_flag , GRP, a_id
```

**Here is my dbfiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5pHiYKyx4yHoirRbGX4kP4/0**

My query does what I need, but it takes to long for a whole day.

Comment: I see "how it must look like", but I cannot understand why so. Explain in details.

Comment: Please describe what login shoudd be implemented

Comment: I edited my question with more details.

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query.

Comment: Here is my db fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5pHiYKyx4yHoirRbGX4kP4/0

Comment: The query at the end of your question is the right way to address the problem. If it's not performing good enough, then you should focus the question on that. Start by sharing the entire `create table` statement for the table, so one can see which indexes you have in place: `show create table tablename`. Providing the execution plan of the query would also be useful: `explain < ... your query ...>`

Comment: I don't think `UNION` is needed at all.

Comment: Please revise your fiddle -- it contains no starts or stops, much less edge cases of a multiple in/outs for an area and a single timestamp for in or out.  Etc.  I suggest this because you are unlikely to get a "correct" answer without including edge cases.

Comment: Can we assume sensors are read exactly every 15 seconds?  I see some shortcuts if I can depend on such.  But they will fall apart if the intervals are not consistent.

Comment: Can I assume you don't care what I say about the start/end of the list?  That is, I don't need to make any assumption about ts0 and ts5, and if I falsely include/exclude a range because of falling off the end, it is OK?

Comment: Your fiddle query can be reduced without UNIONs by simply adding `a.areas_id` to the PARTITIONING. As Rick James wrote, the fiddle data needs improvement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```sql
WITH 
cte1 AS (SELECT CAST(JSON_UNQUOTE(`timestamp`) AS DATETIME) ts,
                areas_id,
                is_in_or_out
         FROM inouts),
cte2 AS (SELECT ts,
                areas_id,
                is_in_or_out,
                CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY areas_id ORDER BY ts ASC) AS SIGNED)
               -CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY areas_id ORDER BY is_in_or_out, ts ASC) AS SIGNED) AS grp
         FROM cte1)
SELECT areas_id, 
       ANY_VALUE(is_in_or_out) is_in_or_out,
       MIN(ts) min_ts,
       MAX(ts) max_ts
FROM cte2 
GROUP BY areas_id, 
         grp
ORDER BY areas_id, min_ts;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3a537e166ed7bef83b1b563025987228)

PS1. Source data was altered slightly.

PS2. `CAST` is needed in MySQL, because `ROW_NUMBER()` produces bigint unsigned. May be replaced with `0.0 + ...`.

Comment: MariaDB gets "FUNCTION range1.ANY_VALUE does not exist".  However, `MIN` is probably a suitable workaround.  (There is a feature request, but no estimate of when it might be implemented.)

Comment: @RickJames Please point me where OP tells something about MariaDB... Speaking about MariaDB one may not only replace ANY_VALUE with MIN/MAX (or remove aggregate function at all but add `is_in_or_out` to GROUP BY expression), but also remove CASTs.

Comment: It was not a critique of your code, it was a warning to those who have MariaDB.

Comment: It does not work if for an area_id, the `is_in_or_out` is at 1 for all the last values, since your `ORDER BY is_in_or_out, ts ASC` will not see the change. See [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ac7fbc5118fc2ad1d5a4e0df01e84224). I changed the grp value to `CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY areas_id ORDER BY ts ASC) AS SIGNED) - (CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY areas_id, is_in_or_out ORDER BY ts ASC) AS SIGNED)+CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY areas_id ORDER BY is_in_or_out, ts ASC) AS SIGNED) ) /2 AS grp` to fix this. But it is not nice.

Answer (score 2):

this is syntax for sql server but should be the same in major dbms

```
with
x as (
    -- find start/end of each period
    select areas_id, is_in_or_out is_flag, timestamp t1
    , ISNULL(ABS(is_in_or_out - LAG(is_in_or_out, 1) over (partition by areas_id order by timestamp)), 1) T_START
    , ISNULL(ABS(is_in_or_out - LEAD(is_in_or_out, 1) over (partition by areas_id order by timestamp)), 1) T_END
    from inouts
),
y as (
    select *, LEAD(t1, 1) over (partition by areas_id order by t1) t2
    from x
    WHERE T_START<>0 OR T_END<>0
)
select areas_id, is_flag, t1 starttime, t2 endtime
from y
WHERE T_START<>0 
order by areas_id, t1
```

shoud do the trick

Comment: If you change `ISNULL` to `IFNULL` it should be compatible with mysql. In this case you can even use `COALESCE`, since all values are integers.

Answer (score 0):

Some more information (like example data and what query is failing) would help but it looks like you could just to a group by.

```
select a_id, is_flag, min(timestamp) as starttime, max(timestamp) as endtime
  from tablename
  group by a_id, is_flag
```

Comment: this doesn't help because it returns a row for each a_id.

Comment: Here is my dbfiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5pHiYKyx4yHoirRbGX4kP4/0; My querry does what I need but it takes to long for a whole day.

Answer (score -1):

What am I missing here? Have you possibly "overthought" things? The SQL below gives the same result set as your example db-fiddle (I tested on a copy), is very much simpler and runs much faster. It gives a row for each areas_id/is_in_or_out combination (per the GROUP BY). I don't quite understand why you need the UNIONs and ROW_NUMBER() OVERs to complicate the query. Hope this helps. Try it out for yourself and let me know if there's any issue!

```
SELECT areas_id,
       starttime,
       endtime,
       is_in_or_out
FROM   (SELECT areas_id,
               MIN(timestamp) starttime,
               MAX(timestamp) endtime,
               is_in_or_out
        FROM   inouts
        GROUP  BY is_in_or_out,
                  areas_id) x
ORDER  BY starttime;
```

P.S. I think MBeale's solution is also actually correct (although it misses the ORDER BY).

Comment: It does not work if you have gaps for an area_id : for instance : `1 1 0 0 1 1`, your group by will only leave 2 rows, whereas we need 3.

Comment: Then you haven't given a "minimum reproducible example" of what you're looking for. As stated, I was able to reproduce your result set with this code.  You need to expand your sample data to clarify this requirement.